# Change a sidebar name?

Tags: functions, sidebar

I'm using a child theme created from a twenty-twelve theme, the theme packs a number of sidebars one which is called "Main Sidebar".

Is it possible to change it's name to something else?

Comment: You have unregister the parent sidebar with `unregister_sidebar` and register your own with the name you want.

Comment: thanks, I'm reading about it. I tried to do it just now but the bar still appears on admin>widgets

Comment: if you suggest it as an answer and complete it a bit, I'll accept. I simply unregistered and registered mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook into `register_sidebar` and change the name after the sidebar was registered.

Example:

```
add_action( 'register_sidebar', function( $sidebar )
{
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    if ( 'Main Sidebar' !== $sidebar[ 'name' ] )
        return;

    $id = $sidebar[ 'id' ];
    $sidebar[ 'name' ] = 'Master';

    $wp_registered_sidebars[ $id ] = $sidebar;
});
```

There is no need to unregister the original if you want to change just the name.

You can change other properties too:

- `description`
- `class`
- `before_widget`, `after_widget`
- `before_title`, `after_title`

Comment: Nice solution, this is cleaner than unregistering and register it again.

Comment: Yes, excellent solution. It may result in an `unexpected T_FUNCTION` error though. Wordpress only requires PHP 5.2.4 but passing an anonymous function as a parameter requires 5.3.

Comment: @epilektric [I did this on purpose](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/the-namespace-wpse).

Comment: @toscho Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Look **functions.php** file of twenty-twelve theme.

there is **twentytwelve_widgets_init** functions for registering sidebar.You can change name of sidebar from there.