# How to use the widget area to extend the page content?

Tags: widgets

I want to remove a widget area (lateral), and extend the page width getting this area. What is the better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easy way:
Simply change your stile.css file.

Replace this code snippet:

```
 /**
* 5.0 Content
*    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

.hentry {
padding: 40px 0;
}

.entry-header,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.entry-meta {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 604px;
width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .entry-header,
.sidebar .entry-content,
.sidebar .entry-summary,
.sidebar .entry-meta {
max-width: 1040px;
padding: 0 376px 0 60px; 
}
```

With this:

```
 /**
* 5.0 Content
*    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

.hentry {
padding: 40px 0;
}

.entry-header,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.entry-meta {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1280px;  /* or the maximum resolution that you want*/
width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .entry-header,
.sidebar .entry-content,
.sidebar .entry-summary,
.sidebar .entry-meta {
max-width: 1040px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;  /* or the right/left padding that you want */
}
```

and disable all the aside zone widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Hook into `register_sidebar` and remove the sidebar from the global array `$wp_registered_sidebars`:

```
add_action( 'register_sidebar', function( $sidebar )
{
    if ( 'lateral' === $sidebar[ 'name' ] )
        unset( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'][ $sidebar[ 'id' ] ] );
});
```

Then adjust the stylesheet or add extra CSS to `wp_head` to let the page content take the full width.

See also: [Change a sidebar name?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112155/change-a-sidebar-name)

Comment: What do you mean with register_sidebar? The sidebar.php file? I have not any register_sidebar file. And wp_head? I have a header.php file that includes the <head> tags.

Comment: `register_sidebar` is the action fired after after a sidebar has been registered by a theme or plugin. `wp_head` is the main action in a theme’s header; you can add new content here with `add_action()`.

Comment: And where are the files which contain these actions?

Comment: These are core files, you should not add your code there, use a [plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web) or [the theme’s `functions.php`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) instead.

Comment: I've tried to add the snippet code at the end of my theme's functions.php file, but nothing changes. Whether I add an aside zone widget, or whether not, the result is the same.